# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class TextChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> ingr = new List<string>();

    void Start()
    {
        ingr.Add("Ingredients:");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = ingr;
    }

    void Lemon()
    {
        ingr.Add("Lemon");
    }

    void Water()
    {
        ingr.Add("Water");
    }
}
```

The only time I mention a string is when I am creating a list, yet it comes up with this error when I run. I am pretty new at C#.

Comment: `GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = ingr;` this is where the error comes

Comment: GetComponent<TextMesh>().text is a string, yet you assign the List<string> to it.

Comment: You can do something like `GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = ingr[0];` or whatever. Right now you're trying to assign the entire `ingr` collection to the `.text` string property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is basically just some text.
`GetComponent<TextMesh>().text` is the text the TextMesh should display, and so it is a string.
In your Update-function, you are trying to set this string to be equal to ingr.

The problem it then tells you, is that ingr is not a string, but a list of strings - it cannot set a single string equal to multiple strings.

One thing that would not give an error is `GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = ingr[0];`
Here, you set the TextMesh's text to the first entry in your list, which seemingly would be "Ingredients:".

I'm guessing what you want though, is for it to also display all the other entries in ingr, with each entry on its own line.
One way to achieve this, is to have ingr be a string instead of a list of strings. Then instead of for example `ingr.Add("Lemon")`, you do: `ingr += "\n Lemon";`.

("\n" is a line break, meaning it makes the text afterwards be on a new line)

This method would make your code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class TextChange : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string ingr = "";

    void Start()
    {
        ingr += "Ingredients:";
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = ingr;
    }

    void Lemon()
    {
        ingr += "Lemon";
    }

    void Water()
    {
        ingr += "Water");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, this is what fixed it for me!

Comment: Just a side note, if you go with the second implementation (using `string` and not `List`), you should use `StringBuilder` which is more efficient with concatenation of strings.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this:

```cs
void Update()
{
  StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (string item in ingr)
  {
    build.Append(item);
    build.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  }

  GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = build.ToString();
}
```

You cannot throw a list into a string...

Comment: Or just `GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = string.Join(",", ingr);`

Answer (score 1):

You are currently setting a Text String to a List of Strings. To fix that you can either

**Replace the List with a String:**

```
public string ingr = "Ingredients:\n";

void Update() {
    GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = ingr;
}

void AddIngredientToList(string ingredient) {
    ingr += ingredient + "\n";
}
```

or you could take each element in your list and add them to a string.

**Join List into a String:**

```
public List<string> ingr = new List<string>();

void Start() {
    ingr.Add("Ingredients:");
}

void Update() {
    GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = string.Join(",", ingr)
}

void AddIngredientToList(string ingredient) {
    ingr.Add(ingredient);
}
```